# MVC ActionLink set ViewBag behind the scene

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an

```
@Html.ActionLink("Search text", "Search", new { q="searchtext1" });
```

that goes to:

http://website2312143.com/search/searchtext1

and I want to set behind the scenes that the actual search text is `"searchtext2"` so I'm trying to pass this value to the `Search` action, but still display http://website2312143.com/search/searchtext1 to the user.

In the `Search` action, I'm trying to get "searchtext2" from the `ViewBag` or any other mechanism and display the data.

The reason why the actual value is different from the url parameter is because the WCF webservice that gets called from the controller needs a slightly different parameter to display the data correctly.

Is there anyway to pass hidden value behind the scene using `@Html.ActionLink` and get that value in the different action without the user noticing any difference?

Comment: do you want to use something like 'q = viewbag.something'  ?

Comment: If I do that, the user will see the URL as /search/searchtext2. I still want to show /search/searchtext1 to the user and pass "searchtext2" to the destination action behind the scene.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444749/how-to-post-data-to-external-site-and-get-external-sites-action-result-from-my     I hope this link will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to do it in slightly different way -

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#me').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parents('form').first().submit();
        });
    });
</script>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Search", new { q = "searchtext1" }, FormMethod.Post))
{ 
    @Html.Hidden("OriginalSearchText", "SearchStringOriginal"); 
    @Html.ActionLink("Search text", "Search", null, new { id = "me" });
}
```

Output -

[image]

and in q, you can get the querystring.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly since `ActionLink` will only ever generate a URL (a `GET`).

You could create a short form that has the `action` set to the `ActionLink` url (You can use `@Url.Action("Search text", "Search", new { q="searchtext1" })` for this too) and then set an `<input type='hidden' value='searchtext2' />`. That would give you the URL you want along with passing a hidden variable.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search text", "Search", new { q = "searchtext1" })
{
   @Html.Hidden("searchtext2", "second search text")
   <input type="submit" value="Search!" class="override so i don't look like a button" />
}
```